# Which data type hold long string

Tags: php, mysql

I want make a field in mysql DB , this field will hold complete header of an email. But now i don't know which data type to select so that it can hold header value. Is longtext type is ok.

Comment: Take your pick: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-types.html

Comment: Yes, `LONGTEXT` sounds okay. Something like [this](http://pastie.org/8899232).

Comment: If I get an email with a header that's the size of a longtext, I'll probably delete that email unread.... that's pretty excessive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Type | Maximum length
-----------+-------------------------------------
  TINYTEXT |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
      TEXT |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Note that the number of characters that can be stored in your column will depend on the character encoding.Please refer -: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: You could also mention `VARCHAR` which goes up to 64 KiB